# Logitech Gamepad F310 interacts with mouse...why?

Tags: mouse, gamepad

I downloaded the N64 emulator off of the Software center a while ago, and I was doing OK with using the keyboard.  Then a friend of mine gave me the brilliant idea of getting a USB controller.  So I got it and it was working fine with the Mupen64Plus, the GFCE Ultra NES, and the ZSNES emulators, until I got the rom for Turok.  The controls are different in that game than the others, and utilizes the four yellow "C" buttons that would be on a N64 controller. The Logitech (F310 if it might be useful to know) I got, looks much more like a PS2 or PS3 controller... four buttons on the right, 2 360 directional sticks that push down as a separate button, etc..

So Turok uses the four yellow "C" buttons as the main movement for it's character.  I don't have so many buttons so I started to mess with using the "U" and "V" axis 360 directional stick.

All of a sudden, the controller started to manipulate the cursor, and before I knew it the mouse arrow was sliding to the top left corner of the screen.  It wouldn't interact with the controller anymore, and the mouse itself, when moved, would move with great resistance back to the top left corner of the screen.

My immediate solution solution was to unplug the controller from the USB.

Now, every time I plug the controller back in, it sends the cursor flailing into the corner of my screen.

I've looked up getting all sorts of "jscalibrators" and other junk from the Software center and I've typed stuff into the terminal from other forums, postings that asked similar questions, but it's been totally hit or miss... mostly miss.

I can't quite figure out what to tell the computer to do to stop thinking the gamepad is the mouse. I been get so frustrated about this over the past two days, I've been taking afternoon naps after researching and fighting for a few hours.

Logitech support hung up on me before even connecting me to a human.

How do I keep the controller from thinking it's the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your xinput configuration:

```
xinput -l
```

You have your gamepad plugged in and it's probably configured under the Core Pointer, not only that but instead of the inputs being button 8, 9 etc. they've been configured to the x/y axis by mistake.

Use xinput to remove the gamepad from the core pointer.

Comment: To save me some time, after I type "xinput -1" into the terminal, I get a list of xinputs and then a variety of possible devices substituted in brackets. I'm not a linux prodigy, and I'm not sure which command to use to remove it. I finagled a little with the terminal, but I don't know precisely what I should write into the brackets. Sorry, I put ubuntu on here to force me to learn a little more about programming.

Comment: I fear that some of the tools you've used have done things which may be broken. You should report these as bugs in the required tools. have a look at `man xinput` to work out how to remove the gamepad from the core pointer, this is something I can't show you.